# Why this string join algorithm takes so much steps?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Based on the book *Cracking the Coding Interview* (page 90), the following algorithm requires O(xn²) time (where 'x' represents a length of the string and 'n' is amount of the strings). The code is in Java. Can anybody explain how we obtain such runtime ?

```java
String joinWords(String[] words)
{
    String sentence = "";
    for(String w : words)
    {
         sentence = sentence + w;
    }

    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: you need to explain more on this problem as from see from it code, it is a list of word and you are iterating on them and addend them to a string, seems like O(N)  operation

Comment: String concatenation yields intermediate string results that will be thrown away again. Because Javas strings are immutable. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: I wouldn't go with `O(N^2)` but rather something like `O(N)` where `N` is the length of all the strings combined. `O(N^2)` (_with `N` as the number of strings_) makes a lot of assumptions about the runtime and implementation details of strings. Basically there would be no such thing as `N^2` if this code was written in a language that does not use immutable strings.

Comment: We would need more context and code to see what operation is `O(n^2)`. The book can always have typo though. Right now the for-loop is simply `O(n)` for `String[] words`

Comment: Listed code is implemented on java

Comment: People who are commenting that this is `O(n)` are assuming string concatenation is `O(1)` which is not true. String concatenation in Java is `O(n)`, so doing it `n` times is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For each string that is concatenated to `sentence`, a new `StringBuilder` is created, two strings are appended to it using the `StringBuilder.append` method, and then the resulting string is created using the `StringBuilder.toString` method. The complexity of this operation is O(n_1 + n_2) where n_1 and n_2 are the lengths of the strings.

In this code, the loop runs n times, and each time it runs, the string `sentence` of length O(xn) is concatenated with the string `w` of length x. Therefore the overall complexity is n * O(xn + x) = O(xn^2), as expected.

---

For the skeptics, here's the disassembled bytecode of the `joinWords` method; I compiled it using `javac` 10.0.1 (which is the version I have to hand at the moment). The StringBuilder is used from positions 25 to 41, which are inside the loop (see `48: goto 12`).

```
  java.lang.String joinWords(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String
       2: astore_2
       3: aload_1
       4: astore_3
       5: aload_3
       6: arraylength
       7: istore        4
       9: iconst_0
      10: istore        5
      12: iload         5
      14: iload         4
      16: if_icmpge     51
      19: aload_3
      20: iload         5
      22: aaload
      23: astore        6
      25: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      28: dup
      29: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      32: aload_2
      33: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      36: aload         6
      38: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      41: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      44: astore_2
      45: iinc          5, 1
      48: goto          12
      51: aload_2
      52: areturn
```

Comment: Also I want to ask about a runtime of the similar [code](https://pastebin.com/V4QprWHm).
Is it O(xn) ?

Comment: Yes, if you use a single StringBuilder to build the whole string, then it's O(xn), because a StringBuilder uses a dynamic array; appending a string of length x is O(x) amortised.